# Where to use small and large argument expansion of plasma dispersion function

Tags: plasma-physics

My question is rather straightforward (at-least that is what I believe  :)):

In plasma physics we have what is known as [plasma dispersion function](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/lectures1/node87.html). There are two approximation under which this function can be expanded: when the argument is **less** than 1, we can use power series expansion and when the argument is **greater** than 1 we can have asymptotic expression.

My question is, given any plasma system, how do we know that under which approximation we have to expand the plasma dispersion function?

Comment: The argument of the plasma dispersion function is generally the phase speed over the thermal speed of the particle species.  You can think of the large(small) argument as being when the phase speed is large(small) or when the thermal speed is small(large).  It depends upon the problem and the type of instability analysis you wish to examine.

Comment: @honeste_vivere, thanks for the input. Lets assume that we have electron, proton and Helium ions. In this scenario, how can be the plasma dispersion function be expanded?

Comment: You would need more information that that.  For what type of modes are you looking?  For instance, if they are "ion" modes, then the electron could be expanded in the small-argument limit.

Comment: I forgot to mention that magnetic field is present.  In this scenario, how about if we wanted to study cyclotron (both proton and Helium) modes and acoustic modes?